# Securing bluetooth LE connection

Tags: security, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently we are setting up a Bluetooth LE device specification and we are running against the following:

The client doesn't want to pair the device via the settings menu. There is a mobile app which should connect to the peripheral.

Now the following, this is the problem:

When connecting, how do we secure our characteristics? We were thinking about prefixing a write request, but what about read requests?

We don't want everybody to see the not so sensitive data. Since it's not sensitive we don't need high security but we still need to secure it some way just in case.

Does anybody know how to do this? How to secure a characteristic?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a challenge-response system on connection - when you connect to the peripheral you read a value from a characteristic which is randomised by the peripheral.  This value has to be hashed in some way using a shared-secret and then written back to the characteristic.  The peripheral then verifies the hashed value. If it matches then it populates the other characteristics and accepts write requests.

Once the central disconnects from the peripheral it ignores write requests and zeros its read characteristics until the next connection/hash handshake.

Answer (score 0):

You must add Security Mode 1 Level 3 to your Services. Then, all the Service's characteristics will be protected.

Comment: For the record, it's a really good thing you edited your post, because you were [dangerously close to having your post deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5959888).

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank you. In fact, I wouldn't really care if other guys deleted it without good reason... the answer serves to help the OP, not myself :) and I believe it was helping him even in the original form.